# localhost Wamp can send email to other mail sever?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, wamp, wampserver

This is my sendmail function in controller

```
    public function sendmail()
{
    $this->load->model("common_model");
    $admin = $this->common_model->get_admin('email,name');

    $this->load->library('email');
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $this->email->initialize($config);  
    $this->email->from($_POST['emailId'], $_POST['firstName']);
    $this->email->to($admin[0]->email);
    $this->email->subject('User Registered For Model :'.base_url());
    $message ="<html> \r\n";
    $message .="<body> \r\n";
    $message .="<table border='0' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='2'>
    <tr><td align='left' colspan='2'>Contact Form:-</td></tr>
    <tr><th colspan='2'>&nbsp;</th></tr>
    <tr><th>Name: </th><td>: ".$_POST['firstName']."</td></tr>
    <tr><th>City: </th><td>: ".$_POST['address']."</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Email: </th><td>: ".$_POST['emailId']."</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Phone: </th><td>: ".$_POST['mobile']."</td></tr>
    <tr><th colspan='2'>&nbsp;</th></tr>";
    $message .= "</table> \r\n";
    $message .= "</body> \r\n";
    $message.="</html> \r\n";
    $this->email->message($message);                
    $this->email->send();
    redirect('myaccount',$data);    
}
```

i am using a wamp server and this is the setting of wamp server

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = you@yourdomain

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path =
```

what changes i have done to send a mail to other server? 
or some error in my function. so i can't send a mail to other mail-server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specifiy an SMTP server where to route the email sent by localhost. `localhost` is not a good value if you haven't installed an SMTP server on your machine. Instead, you should put the SMTP server of your internet provider.

Answer (score -1):

WAMP can't send e-mail. Try to use Test Mail Server Tool to test mail sending from localhost